# How can I decode Access Token Generated by owin Authentication in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i need to decode Token which Generated from Owin Authentication (its contain 4 paramters 1-ClientID 2- UserName 3- Issued 4- Expired) i want to use username in token as a role authentication

Comment: You can use the User object to access an autenticated user in your backend and cherry pick their Claims. The logged in user is baked into your HTTP. For example: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Comment: i used different table called users instead of user

Comment: Shouldn't matter much if you are using them as they are normally used. I guess your authentication details are stored in a cookie? The cookie is issued by your server and encrypted, when it is incoming in a request the server can decrypt it and see its content from there. If you are using tokens, the deal is pretty much the same :)